# Creating an array of superclasses for a particular class

Tags: ruby, loops, superclass

I'm trying to create an array of all the superclasses for the given class. I tried to solve this problem by using a loop. Why is this not working?

```
class Object
  def superclasses
    array = []
    klass = self.superclass
    unless klass == nil
      array << klass
      klass = klass.superclass
    end
    array
  end
end

class Bar
end

class Foo < Bar
end

p Foo.superclasses  # should be [Bar, Object, BasicObject]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unless` isn't a loop. What you're looking for is `until`:

```
class Object
  def superclasses
    array = []
    klass = self.superclass
    until klass == nil
      array << klass
      klass = klass.superclass
    end
    array
  end
end

class Bar
end

class Foo < Bar
end

p Foo.superclasses # Prints "[Bar, Object, BasicObject]"
```

Furthermore, you don't need a new method for this. There's already a method called [`Module#ancestors`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-ancestors) which does basically what you want:

```
class Bar
end

class Foo < Bar
end

p Foo.ancestors # Prints "[Foo, Bar, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]"
```

Note that the return value of `ancestors` includes `Foo` itself, and modules which have been included in the inheritance chain, like `Kernel`. If you don't want that, you can define `superclasses` like this:

```
class Module
  def superclasses
    ancestors[1..-1].select{|mod| mod.is_a? Class }
  end
end

class Bar
end

class Foo < Bar
end

p Foo.superclasses # Prints "[Bar, Object, BasicObject]"
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a loop to continue looking up superclasses:

```
def superclasses
  array = []
  klass = self.superclass
  while klass
    array << klass
    klass = klass.superclass
  end
  array
end
```

I think it looks a bit nicer to use recursion

```
def superclasses
  return [] if superclass.nil?
  [superclass].concat superclass.superclasses
end
```

And really this method should be defined in `Class` because not every `Object` responds to `superclass`.

Ruby's built-in way of doing this is [`Module#ancestors`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-ancestors). It's not exactly the same though, because that also takes into account included modules. The built-in way is the correct way to do this, however, since the strict chain of superclasses doesn't really give you the whole picture in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get superclasses

```
class Object
  def superclasses
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).select { |klass| klass < self }
  end
end
```

Comment: Woah, you want to look through the entire object space of classes just to find one object's superclasses? That's terribly inefficient. A brand new IRB instance gives `ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).count #=> 368`. So you're basically looking through 368+ objects just to find which of them are superclasses? Under most circumstances this probably isn't a good solution.